# Magento EE 1.11 - Customer Attributes Not Visible

Tags: magento, attributes

Our client wants to add an 'Industry' dropdown to customer registration. We have created a new customer attribute, 'industry' and entered in the appropriate values.

It was not showing on the front-end. I looked into `customer/form/register.phtml` and it wasn't calling anything for attributes, so I pulled from `enterprise/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml` the following:

```
<?php $customerAttributes = $this->getChild('customer_form_user_attributes');?>
<?php if ($customerAttributes): ?>
    <?php $customerAttributes->setShowContainer(false);?>
    <?php $this->restoreSessionData($customerAttributes->getForm());?>
    <?php echo $customerAttributes->toHtml()?>
<?php endif;?>
```

And then I added in the .xml update found in 'enterprise/layout/customer.xml':

```
<remove name="right"/>
<remove name="left"/>
<reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before"     translate="label">
<label>Form Fields Before</label>
<!--action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action-->
<action method="setElementClass"><value>rewards</value></action>
</block>
<block type="enterprise_customer/form" template="customer/form/userattributes.phtml" name="customer_form_user_attributes">
<action method="setFormCode"><code>customer_account_create</code></action>
<action method="setEntityModelClass"><code>customer/customer</code></action>
</block>
<block type="enterprise_customer/form" template="customer/form/userattributes.phtml" name="customer_form_address_user_attributes">
<action method="setFormCode"><code>customer_register_address</code></action>
<action method="setEntityModelClass"><code>customer/address</code></action>
</block>
<reference name="content">
<block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
    <action method="append"><block>customer.form.register.fields.before</block>          <alias>form_fields_before</alias></action>
    <action method="append"><block>customer_form_user_attributes</block>    </action>
    <action method="append">    <block>customer_form_address_user_attributes</block></action>
</block>
</reference>
<update handle="customer_form_template_handle"/>
```

At this point, the attributes are not visible on the front-end. If I perform:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($customerAttributes->getUserDefinedAttributes()) ?>
</pre>
```

I am returned the array of attributes as I would expect. What am I missing here?

Comment: did you select where will available this attribute from "Forms to use in" sction? There are four area to show this attribute which is one of them "Customer Registration".

Comment: Indeed, all options are set correctly. On the front-end, the <ul> that contains the elements is there, but it's empty. As well, when turning on template path hints, the template is loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Needed this stuff in customer.xml. For some reason using the enterprise/default customer.xml wasn't working, but I added this in and it was good.

```
<customer_form_template_handle>
    <reference name="content">
        <block name="customer_form_template" type="enterprise_customer/form_template">
            <action method="addRenderer">
                <type>text</type>
                <renderer_block>enterprise_customer/form_renderer_text</renderer_block>
                <template>customer/form/renderer/text.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addRenderer">
                <type>textarea</type>
                <renderer_block>enterprise_customer/form_renderer_textarea</renderer_block>
                <template>customer/form/renderer/textarea.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addRenderer">
                <type>multiline</type>
                <renderer_block>enterprise_customer/form_renderer_multiline</renderer_block>
                <template>customer/form/renderer/multiline.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addRenderer">
                <type>date</type>
                <renderer_block>enterprise_customer/form_renderer_date</renderer_block>
                <template>customer/form/renderer/date.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addRenderer">
                <type>select</type>
                <renderer_block>enterprise_customer/form_renderer_select</renderer_block>
                <template>customer/form/renderer/select.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addRenderer">
                <type>multiselect</type>
                <renderer_block>enterprise_customer/form_renderer_multiselect</renderer_block>
                <template>customer/form/renderer/multiselect.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addRenderer">
                <type>boolean</type>
                <renderer_block>enterprise_customer/form_renderer_boolean</renderer_block>
                <template>customer/form/renderer/boolean.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addRenderer">
                <type>file</type>
                <renderer_block>enterprise_customer/form_renderer_file</renderer_block>
                <template>customer/form/renderer/file.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addRenderer">
                <type>image</type>
                <renderer_block>enterprise_customer/form_renderer_image</renderer_block>
                <template>customer/form/renderer/image.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_form_template_handle>
```

Comment: I have created new customer address attribute with type 'yes/no'.
Its showing correctly on register form with default value 'No' as selected. but it do not show the values selected for existing customers in their my account. It shows 3 options , a blank value selected and "Yes" and "No"..
Any idea how do i get the default value selected for existing customer. I have already reindex the data and clear cache.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check `template/customer/form/userattributes.phtml` which is controlling user defined attributes. I don't know, does anybody touched this file? Check this first.

```
    <?php foreach ($this->getUserDefinedAttributes() as $attribute):?>
        <?php $attributeContent = $this->getAttributeHtml($attribute);?>
            <?php if ($attributeContent): ?>
               <li><?php echo $attributeContent;?></li>
            <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: The enterprise/default/customer/form/userattributes.phtml and our_theme/deafult/customer/form/userattributes.phtml are exactly the same; however, when I switch the package to 'enterprise/default' the attributes show up properly, so there must be something different somewhere, even though the .xml and both template files are all the same as 'enterprise/default'.

Comment: I have created new customer address attribute with type 'yes/no'.
Its showing correctly on register form with default value 'No' as selected. but it do not show the values selected for existing customers in their my account. It shows 3 options , a blank value selected and "Yes" and "No"..
Any idea how do i get the default value selected for existing customer. I have already reindex the data and clear cache.

Thanks